# Screen automatically dims

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, brightness

So, I have a W10 HP ENVY laptop, I'm used to code with a dark themed IDLE, the thing is, the screen automatically dims whenever i'm using some dark themed program, but when I open a bright program (google's homepage for example) the screen does not return to it's normal brightness level... and stays dim until i manually set the brightness back up again.
I don't know why this happens, but I don't like it.
Any help?